# Comparing a formula column with value column in excel

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have two columns in a excel sheet. I am populating the first column with a formula and I have some values in second column. Now I want to compare these two columns and need to display True/false in third column. But when I use 'IF' condition all I am getting is FALSE. Here is my code.

#### Formulating the column

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[GetConfigValue("Reconsheet")];
    int totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;


    for (int row = startupRow; row <= totalRows; row++)
    {
        //Formula
        string vlookforH = "IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C" + row + ",PWA!A:B,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(C" + row + ",PWA!A:B,2,FALSE))";
        worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Formula = vlookforH;

    }
    xlPackage.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("PWA hours received");
}
```

#### Comparing Formula column and Normal value column:

```
for (int row = startupRow; row <= totalRows; row++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(worksheet.Cells[row, 18].Value) != 0)
    {

        decimal hvalue = (worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value) != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value.ToString()) : 0;
        decimal rvalue = (worksheet.Cells[row, 18].Value) != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[row, 18].Value.ToString()) : 0;

        if (hvalue == rvalue)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, 31].Value = "True";
        }
        else
        {
            worksheet.Cells[row,31].Value = "False";
            Count = Count + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

When I am debugging the application, I realized `hvalue` is always zero because it's a formula column.

I've tried in different ways, but unable to find the solution. Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried validating your Excel formulas within a normal excel sheet?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. I am getting it correctly

Comment: ok give me a second I'll try my luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to call `worksheet.Calculate();` after writing the formulas into the cells to actually calculate the values. Calling it once after your first for-loop is enough.

I verified that on a test-project.

EDIT:
If worksheet.Calculate() does not work you can try `xlPackage.Workbook.Calculate();`

Here is a link to the documentation: [EPPlus Calculate Documentation](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am getting an error. 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet' does not contain a definition for 'Calculate' and no extension method 'Calculate' accepting a first argument of type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Which nuget package are you using exactly?
Looks like EPPlus. I tried it with v 4.5.3.1 and it worked.

Comment: i am using EPPlus

Comment: Version? You can check your version with right click on the project and then "Manage NuGet Packages"

Comment: I am getting nothing in 'Manage NuGet Packages'. However EPPlus version is 3.1.3.0. Spare with me as i am beginner in .net

Comment: Okey then there is the problem. Calculate was added in version 4 onwards.
Can you possibly update your EPPlus version?
(for example via the nuget package manager)